# Is there a mechanism for reporting the eventual resolution of the topic of a question? If so, what?

Tags: discussion

This question is prompted by Olin Lathrop's question [Wood versus plastic trail signs?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/wood-versus-plastic-trail-signs), but I am sure there are a few similar cases where some users would like to know: "what eventually happened?"

I'd be interested to know what the Trails Committee of Groton MA decided about wood vs plastic trail signs. Do I just ask Lathrop in a comment, and would he (if so inclined) report back in a comment -- or what?

Comment: Thanks for asking this! I'm no expert by any means, especially on this site, but at Gardening and Landscaping, we tend to leave a comment in a case like this, especially if the profile shows that the user's around fairly often. I'd like to know what happened with that too, so now that Rory Alsop has suggested it, I hope you drop Olin a note. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Done.  You should have received a copy of the comment.  If not, go to the original Q -- my comment for further info is at the bottom of a long list of comments under the Q.

Comment: Great, thanks for doing that, and for mentioning me too. That was nice of you. :)  That question drew a lot of attention, so I agree that we're probably not the only people wondering about the outcome.

Comment: I noticed @Olin Lathrop responded to your comment. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sue (addressing you since ab2 will automatically get notified): I added a new answer to that question detailing what happened.  Sorry it took so long to close the loop.  I wasn't aware of this meta question until today (rarely check meta on this site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest in a case like this popping a comment on the original post asking them what happened. They may not respond, but the notification should get to them if they are still active, so they have a chance to respond.

If they are no longer active on the site, there may be nothing you can do.